# how to solve the Deprecated problem For SEO

Tags: php, html, api

I've just got an error.

When I try to assign an object like this: am doing  for SEO by google php seo scripts.

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 3703

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 3876

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 3896

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on line 1451

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\searchgoosimple.php on line 89
Sorry, no search results found
```

The error I get is "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated". Actually I've been looking for a solution but the only one I've seen is just turn down the politicy of nusoap.php (error_reporting). I've tried it too, but it didn't work.

It's so confusing..I hope you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these error messages carries a line number and a filename:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\subgoogle\nusoap.php on **line 3703**

Go there, and remove the `&` before the `new`.

To get rid of the other warnings, use following setting in your main script to reduce the error reporting level:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll have to find eventual other instances of `error_reporting(` and adapt them too.