# how to remove the deprecated error

Tags: php, javascript, html, api

I'm developing google clone search engine with Google API key in PHP. I'm getting this error. what should I do for remove that error?

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\downclone\google.com-search-engine-clone\google.com Search Engine Clone\nusoap.php on line 3703
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814387/how-to-solve-the-deprecated-problem-for-seo

Comment: On the production server you should avoid displaying of all the errors, not only those deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED );
```

Ideally you should change the actual code so it doesn't use deprecated functionality ( in this case remove `&` before `new` in the line referenced ) .. but if you do not have the time/resources then nullify it using the above.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP5 this is deprecated

Remove `&` before `new`

[Check This Out](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=634670)